# JUnit tests in Spring Boot 3.0 does not work

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

#### Code

GET method inside controller class:

```java
@GetMapping("/getAllRecommendedMovies")
public ResponseEntity<BookMyTicket> getAllRecommendedMovies(
  @RequestParam(value = "theatreName", required = false) String theatreName,
  @RequestParam(value = "pincode", required = false) Integer pincode,
  HttpServletRequest request) {

  return Observation.createNotStarted(
    request.getRequestURI().substring(1),
    observationRegistry
  ).observe(() -> new ResponseEntity<(
    theatreManagementService.getAllRecommendedMovies(theatreName, pincode),
    HttpStatus.OK
  ));

}
```

JUnit test:

```java
@Test
public void getAllRecommendedMovies() throws Exception {
  try (MockedStatic<Observation> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(Observation.class)) {
    utilities.when(
      () -> Observation.createNotStarted(Mockito.eq("getAllRecommendedMovies"), Mockito.any())
    ).thenReturn(Observation.NOOP);
  }
  mockMvc.perform(get("/getAllRecommendedMovies")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Also on Github: [TheatreManagementControllerTest.java](https://github.com/Joseph24x7/BookMyTicket/blob/main/src/test/java/com/bookmyticket/controller/TheatreManagementControllerTest.java)

#### Question

I have implemented JUnit test for `ObservationRegistry`.

Is there any alternate method to implement?

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need the complete code - also classes `Observation`, maybe class for `observationRegistry`. What exactly is not working - any error-output or unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito.mockStatic` can only mock static calls that happen in the same thread. See https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks.
Spring MVC tests run the Spring application in its own thread so static mocking with Mockito won't help here.

I suggest you introduce a `ObservationService` interface to wrap methods like `Observation.createNotStarted(..)` and use that service in your controller. The service can then be easily mocked using standard Spring testing mechanisms like `@MockBean`.